# Dockerfile: Copied file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to add a shell script to a container, and then run it as part of my build.

Here's the relevant section of the dockerfile:

```
#phantomjs install
COPY conf/phantomjs.sh ~/phantomjs.sh
RUN chmod +x ~/phantomjs.sh && ~/phantomjs.sh
```

And here's the output during the build:

```
Step 16 : COPY conf/phantomjs.sh ~/phantomjs.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8199d97eb936
Step 17 : RUN chmod +x ~/phantomjs.sh && ~/phantomjs.sh
 ---> Running in 3c7ecb307bd3
[91mchmod: [0m[91mcannot access '/root/phantomjs.sh'[0m[91m: No such file or directory[0m[91m
```

the file I'm copying exists in the conf folder underneath the build directory... but whatever I do it doesn't seem to be copied across.

Comment: Had the same issue, and replacing the ~ fixed it, as outlined in the answers.

Answer (score 10):

#### TL;DR

Don't rely on shell expansions like `~` in `COPY` instructions. Use `COPY conf/phantomjs.sh /path/to/user/home/phantomjs.sh` instead!

#### Detailed explanation

Using `~` as shortcut for the user's home directory is a feature offered by your shell (i.e. Bash or ZSH). `COPY` instructions in a Dockerfile are not run in a shell; they simply take file paths as an argument (also see the [manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)).

This issue can easily be reproduced with a minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
COPY test ~/test
```

Then build and run:

```
$ echo foo > test
$ docker built -t test
$ docker run --rm -it test /bin/sh
```

When running `ls -l /` *inside the container*, you'll see that `docker build` did not expand `~` to `/root/`, but actually created the directory named `~` with the file `test` in it:

```
/ # ls -l /~/test.txt 
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             7 Jan 16 12:26 /~/test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

not sure, but maybe `~` in the Dockerfile is referencing your `$HOME`, `/home/$USER` on the host.

i would try to change the reference from `~` or `$HOME` to explicit folder `/root`:

```
#phantomjs install
COPY conf/phantomjs.sh /root/phantomjs.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/phantomjs.sh && /root/phantomjs.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`~` isnt a context understood by Docker when you use the `COPY` command. It will simply create a folder named ~ as in /~/phantomjs.sh .
 Use `$HOME` to reference or an explicit mention of the path to use this in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

download the required file from github repo into Build folder and run the build command again, it will pickup the file during build process.